# How to use Trello API with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, api, trello

I am new to using the Trello API and am using asp.net

I have built an asp.net form containing card information. I want to save the form information into Trello, as a new card, instead of storing it in my database.

Answer (score 0):

First add the script key to the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=yourAppKeyGoesHere"></script>
```

Log in to Trello and [go to this URL to get your Application key.](https://trello.com/app-key)

This code can be used to authorize the user with your application:

```
Trello.authorize({
type: "redirect",
name: "YourWebsite.com",
scope: {
    read: true,
    write: true,
    account: true
},
error: function () { onFailedAuthorization(); },
expiration: "never"
});
function onFailedAuthorization() {
    alert("Trello login failed.")
}
```

You can then use a function like this to Create a card in Trello:

```
function CreateCard(cardName, Descr, listID, dueDate)
var newCard = 
{
    name: cardName, desc: Descr, pos: "top", idList: listID, due: dueDate, idMembers: member.id
 };
 Trello.post("/cards", newCard)
```

The idList can be found by opening a card in the Trello List. Add `.json` to the URL and search the JSON for idList.

[Visit the Trello API Docs for more info.](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference)